# Correlation between two matrices with the same features but different samples

Tags: correlation, multivariate-analysis

I've been reading about mantel tests and Procrustes but I can't quite figure out if they require the samples to the same in matrix 1 and matrix 2?

Basically it's the same features measured in multiple groups of samples and I want to examine if some groups are more highly correlated with each other than the other groups.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this quote from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantel_test) helps (emphasis is mine):

> The [Mantel] test is commonly used in ecology, where the data are usually estimates of the "distance" between objects such as species of organisms. For example, **one matrix might contain estimates of the genetic distances** (i.e., the amount of difference between two different genomes) between all possible pairs of species in the study, obtained by the methods of molecular systematics; **while the other might contain estimates of the geographical distance** between the ranges of each species to every other species.

So the rows and columns refer to the species but the entries are different samples, in the sense that they are measures of genetic difference (measured as a fixation index, say) and geographical distance (measured in kilometers, say).